# how to: re-assemble machine generated classes from xsd files to their original nested state

Tags: .net, xsd, xsd.exe, xmlserializer

I'm working in Visual Studio 2008 using c#.

Let's say I have 2 xsd files e.g "Envelope.xsd" and "Body.xsd"

I create 2 sets of classes by running xsd.exe, creating something like "Envelope.cs" and "Body.cs", so far so good.

I can't figure out how to link the two classes to serialize (using XmlSerializer) into the proper nested xml, i.e:

I want:
`<Envelope><DocumentTitle>Title</DocumentTitle><Body>Body Info</Body></Envelope>`

But I get:
`<Envelope><DocumentTitle>Title</DocumentTitle></Envelope><Body>Body Info</Body>`

Could someone perhaps show me how the two .cs classes should look to enable XmlSerializer to runt the desired nested result?

Thanks a million

Paul

Comment: Can you post the relevant bit of the schema? `XmlSerializer` should write back as the schema wants it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to do it (sample console program):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    [XmlRoot("Envelope")]
    public class EnvelopeClass
    {
        [XmlElement("DocumentTitle")]
        public string DocumentTitle { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Body")]
        public BodyClass BodyElement { get; set; }
    }

    public class BodyClass
    {
        [XmlText()]
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EnvelopeClass envelope =
                new EnvelopeClass
                {
                    DocumentTitle = "Title",
                    BodyElement = new BodyClass { Body = "Body Info" }
                };

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EnvelopeClass));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
            xs.Serialize(writer, envelope);
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <Envelope 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <DocumentTitle>Title</DocumentTitle>
      <Body>Body Info</Body>
    </Envelope>
```

Hope that helps!  Remember to mark my post answered pleez...  :)